# Two different versions of a profile - react navigation, AWS, Amplify, Appsync

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, aws-appsync

I have an app that after signing up, the users are split into 2 groups/types of users and depending on which group the user chooses, the profile page and options on the profile page displayed will be different.

For example: after signing up the user is presented with a question: "Are you using this app as a Teacher or a Student?" The answer they choose is sent to the API (Appsync) to create a new StudentProfile or a new TeacherProfile based on their choice. They are then redirected to the app and I need to find a way to then say if this user is a teacher display the Teacher Profile Page under the Profile Tab or if this user is a Student display the Student Profile Page. The rest of the app is the same (its just the profile page Tab which is different/ has different design and options depending on weather or not you are a student or a Teacher.)

```
Tabs
 -- SettingsStack
 -- HomeStack
 -- SearchStack
 -- InboxStack
 -- ProfileStack_Teacher || ProfileStack_Student
```

Does anyone know how I would go about creating this?

I am using:
React-Native, React-Navigation, AWS Amplify and Appsync.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the built in [`__typename`](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#meta-fields) field.

If you include this in your query, you'll be able to see if the Profile you've been returned is a `StudentProfile` or `TeacherProfile` and display the correct component accordingly.